# how to remove part of the string if the condition exists

Tags: awk, sed, gsub

I have a file similar to this:

```
   A*01:03:05
   B1*02:06:08
   F2*03:01:06
   R5*02:01
   S1*02:08
```

And would like to remove the last 2 numbers and the colon, only when there are 2 colon separators. so it will be:

```
   A*01:03
   B1*02:06
   F2*03:01
   R5*02:01
   S1*02:08
```

The last 2 lines remain unchanged because they do not have 2 colon separators after the *, so no changes are made to those values

I used `sed` and `gsub` to remove everything after the last underscore but was not sure how to add a condition to exempt the condition when I do not have 2 colons after the *.

Comment: Kindly do add your efforts in your question which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
$ sed -E 's/^([^:]*:[^:]*):[0-9][0-9]$/\1/' file
```

The `[^:]` means 'any character other than a :' so it works by making the deletion at the end only if there are two leading colons.

This `awk` works too:

```
$ awk 'gsub(/:/,":")==2 {sub(/:[0-9][0-9]$/,"")} 1' file
```

In this case, `gsub` returns the number of replacements made. So if there are two colons, delete the ending.

You can also use GNU grep (with PCRE) to only match the template of what you are looking for:

```
$ grep -oP '^\w+\*\d\d:\d\d' file
```

Or `perl` same way:

```
$ perl -lnE 'say "$1" if /(^\w+\*\d\d:\d\d)/' file
```

Comment: offtopic: `*:[^:]*` portion is showing up as italic for me on desktop browser

Comment: @Sundeep: me too, but I think that is a SO markdown issue, isn't it? I did not apply formatting to the code...

Comment: yeah, sorry didn't mean it's an issue from your side.. before commenting, I clicked edit to see if I can spot any issue, but preview shows up fine in that case..

Answer (score 4):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/:..//2' file
```

This removes the second occurrence of a `:` followed by 2 characters.

If this is too lax, use:

```
sed -E 's/^([^:]*:[^:]*):[0-9]{2}/\1/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

With `cut`, you can set `:` as delimiter and print only upto first two fields

```sh
cut -d: -f-2 ip.txt
```

Similar logic can be done with `awk`, assuming the implementation supports manipulating `NF`

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} NF==3{NF=2} 1' ip.txt
```